# OnAudioFilterRead: where are VU meter and time spent shown in the editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

In the documentation of [MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html), the following is written:

> If OnAudioFilterRead is implemented a VU meter is shown in the
> Inspector displaying the outgoing sample level. The process time of
> the filter is also measured and the spent milliseconds are shown next
> to the VU meter. The number turns red if the filter is taking up too
> much time, meaning the mixer will be starved of audio data.

But these widgets are nowhere to be seen in the Inspector...

There is also this other option in a mixer's context menu:

[image]

But again, nothing is ever shown anywhere in the editor...

[The registry key](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/AudioMixerGroupEditor.cs#L16) this option updates is indeed set to `1` but that's all.

**What I've tried:**

Using Unity 2022.3.3f1, created a brand new project.

Created the most basic setup and added this script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Volume = 0.5f;

    public void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] *= Volume;
        }
    }
}
```

The callback indeed works as I can change volume but no VU nor CPU meter:

[image]

Whether or not a mixer is plugged-in makes no difference.

Tried to restart Unity but that didn't change anything.

**Question:**

Why are the VU and CPU meters nowhere to be seen on the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, an `Editor` must be created for it to appear:

The component:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Whatever
{
    public class WhateverComponent : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The editor:

```
using UnityEditor;

namespace Whatever
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(WhateverComponent))]
    internal sealed class WhateverComponentEditor : Editor
    {
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: huh?! That sounds like some dirty workaround :D I'd still claim that's a weird bug ^^ but yeah .. workaround works for me as well :D nice find

Comment: I wanted to try disable the new UI elements based inspector to see if it's related to it, but it they finally hid that setting that was present on older versions. But now I realize that these meters are barely useful, they are green, yet CPU usage is still very high after profiling the audio code. Applying an FIR filter to the incoming audio is literally a CPU hog, going to try Burst to see if I can further get these numbers down.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the according

```
void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{
    ...
}
```

implemented in one of your `MonoBehaviour` components?

You then also need to be in **Play Mode** an it will add the following visuals to that component (using the example from [`OnAudioFilterRead`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html)):

[image]

Comment: I do, updated the question explaining the setup. What version of Unity are you using? Starting to think that it might be a bug in Unity itself...

Comment: @aybe hmm looks like either a bug or something that was turned off by default maybe ... it works in `2020.3 LTS`, `2021.3 LTS` ... it is gone in `2022.3 LTS` and `2023.1`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Unity 2023.1 and the VU Meter is missing here too.
I am pretty sure that it was there while using 2021.3.1.

Comment: Never used it until today so I cannot tell, could very much be a bug in Unity.

Comment: It kinda looks like that.
the VU Meter appears under the Component in Version 2021.3.2f1
but it does NOT appear in 2023.1.1f1